# Can I switch my dog's food back to what they were using?

Tags: dogs, diet

When we got our dog, our dog was being fed this [dog food, Black Gold Explorer Super Performance Formula 32/21.](https://www.chewy.com/black-gold-explorer-super-performance/dp/579774) Per our vet's recommendation, we switched to [this dog food, Hill's Science Diet Puppy Chicken Meal & Barley.](https://www.chewy.com/hills-science-diet-puppy-chicken-meal/dp/37837)

We slowly transition the dog to the new food following the instructions on the back on the dog food.

We feed our dog twice a day, once in the morning and once at night.

Over the last couple of weeks, our dog only likes to eat at night and no longer eats in the morning. Does our dog not like his food? Should we go back to the food he was originally eating?

Comment: Is your dog having any other issues, like Vomiting or anything like that?

Comment: Not at all- looks like he's feeling fine and he's the same playful pup. The only thing that's changed is his eating times. He's just less excited by his food.

Comment: What's your vet's reasoning for switching?

Comment: They didn't share their exact reasoning, other than their practice recommends two brands for dogs (Hill's Science and Purina Pro Plan). Our vet mentioned she never heard of the brand our dog was previously using.

Answer (score 2):

It might be hard for anyone to responsibly answer this question without knowing why your vet recommended the switch in diet. Both of these foods are appropriate for puppies but there might be other reasons the vet thinks Hill's Science is more fitting for your pup.

What I can say here though is that I think it's less of a concern if your dog is eating twice a day versus whether they're getting enough of their calories a day. If your puppy is happy eating **all** their daily intake calories once a day in the evening I would not think that should be a reason for concern.

You could try seeing if he'll eat his entire daily meal at night and if he does I wouldn't worry much further. (It could be that the morning activity of your house distracts him or is more appealing to him than his breakfast.) But if he's under-eating and you strongly suspect it's because of the brand, I'd suggest reaching out to your vet about switching back. This sounds like a question they could answer over phone or email and shouldn't warrant an appointment.